# Doing basic structured layout in core

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am building a Vaadin app to handle processing of documents.  The main page for the application is a status view that should show counts of documents in various states, along with snapshot information of automated processes.  In the Bootstrap + Thymeleaf world, this is a blend of col and row divs, spans, and labels.  With Vaadin, what makes sense for creating this kind of UI?  Is this a bunch of small grid objects instead of the big nested div concept?

Here's some information that I want to display in a "nice" layout:

```
Documents:
 237 unprocessed
 45 in progress
 33 complete

Process Queue:
 45 Priority Pending
 297 Priority Complete
 22 Pending
 65 Complete

Asynch Runner 1:
  Name: Generate Thumbnail
  State: Complete
  Last Update: 2024-01-07T16:11:55
Asynch Runner 2:
  Name: Rotate Original
  State: In Process
  Last Update: 2024-01-04T12:14:55
```

Comment: Use Thymeleaf to generate HTML and show it using the `Html` class.